# http wait for another call finish

Tags: angular

**scenario**:

- members and non-members have different contents in the same page, e.g. news, user info
- "remember me" feature is available
- check the token in local storage with server to verify user when website is loaded
- most of http request result will be different based on login status

**problem**:

- how can I wait for user validation before all http request is triggered?

**http.service.ts sample code**:

```
  private isReady = false;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.init();
  }

  // pass local data to check user login status
  // check the token, expired date etc.
  public init() {
    // this.httpClient.post to verify user status
    // this.isReady = true;
  }

  // http get request used in other components
  public get(url) {
    if (this.isReady) {
      return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.apiRoot + url);
    } else {
      // how to wait for init() is done before return in here?
      return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.apiRoot + url);
    }
  }
```

sandbox sample is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-firefly-z5t4h?file=/src/app/http.service.ts)

Comment: There are several ways of solving this. One way would be to make your isReady property into an Observable. Then you could wait for the isReady observable to be true inside your get(url) method.

Comment: Make use of ngAfterInit() , call function within this method . This method would trigger when init() is done

Comment: Hi SnorreDan, could you give me some sample or reference url? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. In app component

```
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.http.init(); // wait until init complete

    // Then call your other things
  }
```

HttpService.ts

```
public async init(): Promise<void> {
    await this.httpClient
      .get<any>(this.apiRoot + "assets/user.json")
      .toPromise()
      .then(s => {
        console.log("init completed");
      });
  }
```

This is the [code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/still-sun-v47os?file=/src/app/http.service.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it will block other initial processing, not suitable in my case.